# Convert raw Android image to png

Tags: android, png, screenshot

On a rooted Android device, i want to take a screenshot and convert the raw format image to a Png image then save it locally. So far, i managed to access the framebuffer, take the screenshot and save the raw image. The problem is when i convert it to Png format, the image i get is all wrong.. a bunch of white and grey lines. 
Here's what i did:

```
public void putRawImageInArray (byte [] array, File f ) throws IOException{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")

    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));   //The framebuffer raw image is in the file
    bufferedInputStream.read(array, 0, array.length);//read the file
} 

public void convertToBitmap (byte [] rawarray) throws IOException{
            byte [] Bits = new byte[rawarray.length*4]; 
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<rawarray.length;i++)
            {
                Bits[i*4] =
                    Bits[i*4+1] =
                    Bits[i*4+2] = (byte) ~rawarray[i]; 
                Bits[i*4+3] = -1;//0xff, that's the alpha.
            }


            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(Bits)); 

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/pictures/picture.png");
            f.createNewFile();
            if (f.exists() == true) {
                f.delete();
            }
try{
            OutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your image appears gray because you are setting all RGB values to the same (the recipe for "gray"). What is the color model of the original data? You assume it's 1-byte (color indexed?). Do you get recognizable data when writing the raw data immediately to a file? Use a good hex viewer to check.

Comment: Can you paste it here code snippet from where you are calling `convertToBitmap`?

Comment: I call it from a class within the same activity:                 class PullScreenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         while(true)
         {                                                  /* #1: Access the framebuffer, get the screenshot, and save the image.raw in the file                                             #2: Create a byte array and call  putRawImageInArray()              #3: Call convertToBitmap()      */                                        }}}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all this

```
    byte [] Bits = new byte[rawarray.length*4]; 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<rawarray.length;i++)
    {
        Bits[i*4] =
            Bits[i*4+1] =
            Bits[i*4+2] = (byte) ~rawarray[i]; 
        Bits[i*4+3] = -1;//0xff, that's the alpha.
    }
```

and use rawarray directly

```
 Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(rawarray));
```

and make sure that the color model that you are using(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) is same as the color model of the image data.

Comment: thanks for ur answer .. when i delete that block of code, i get a total black png image.